# Lyx can't find csquotes in TeXLive 2018, but I can

Tags: lyx, csquotes

I have many lyx docs that use csquotes.

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

They worked fine with TeXLive 2017, but since upgrading to TeXLive 2018, I get the following error at load time:

[image: csquotes missing from Lax 2.3.0]

TeX Live Utility set to the 2018 distro shows the csquotes package:

[image: csquotes in TeXLive 2018]

I've reconfigured LyX 2.3.0 but the problem persists. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your OS? When and how did you install TL 2018? What version of the csquotes do you have installed on your computer? It seems there was a problem a month ago: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-May/041586.html. Did you update TL 2018 after you installed it? In LyX, if you do File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex) and then compile that .tex file manually, does it compile without error? (check the exit code).

Comment: Run `kpsewhich squires.sty` in Terminal and let us know what it returns.

Comment: A LyX module is not the same as a LaTeX package. A module defines a LyX interface to specific features of packages. I see there is a `csquotes` module at https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules, you probably need that.

Comment: The csquotes version is:  2018/04/113 v5.2d. The OS is OSX 10.13.1 . 
I installed TeXLive from the official MacOS image. Compiling the TeX export works without error. kpewhich returns nothing.

Comment: Also, I keep TeXLive 2018 up to date, but the issue persists.

Comment: TorbjørnT.'s comment is the correct answer. You need the module (which is just a text file). Follow the link in his comment. To learn more about LyX modules, see the LyX help files in the "Help" menu.

Comment: ... and it's fixed. Been a while since I used Lyx and I confused the message about the csquotes module with the TeX package. My bad. 
Thanks for all the the help.

Comment: @Ron I actually did the same thing (I read too quickly through your post). Good thing Torbjørn T. is more careful than us :). By the way, the linebreaking on that LyX dialog is pretty ugly. If you are motivated and make a trac ticket, I will (eventually) take a look to try to fix that: https://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: @TorbjørnT. could you make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A LyX module is not the same as a LaTeX package, the error indicates that the csquotes module (can be found at https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules) is not available for your LyX installation. That module provides a LyX interface to the package with the same name, but otherwise the two are completely separate.

Comment: @scottkosty Oops, sorry about that. I deleted the second paragraph.